# We're open extension not working

Tags: extensions, magento-1.6

I'm using the following extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/we-re-open.html

I got an error loading it on my site:

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html::_(Array
(
    [0] => CLOSED
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/design/frontend/tx3-package/tx3-theme/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(46): Varien_Object->__call('_', Array)
#1 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/design/frontend/tx3-package/tx3-theme/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(46): Mage_Page_Block_Html->_('CLOSED')
#2 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/tx3shop/d...')
#3 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tx3-pa...')
#4 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#8 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#9 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#11 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/tx3shop/domains/tx3shop.be/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

I contacted the author, but got no response :(

The code I use to load the block:

```
<?php
$dow=array('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun');
foreach($dow as $day) {
  ${$day.'_open'}  = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.$day.'_open');
  ${$day.'_close'} = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.$day.'_close');
}
?>
<div class="fullschedule">
<div id="header">
<?php echo "<strong>".$this->__('Business Hours')."</strong>\n" ?>
</div>
<div id="schedule">
<?php
foreach($dow as $day) {
  switch($day) {
    case 'mon': echo $this->__('Monday');
              break;
    case 'tue': echo $this->__('Tuesday');
              break;
    case 'wed': echo $this->__('Wednesday');
              break;
    case 'thu': echo $this->__('Thursday');
              break;
    case 'fri': echo $this->__('Friday');
              break;
    case 'sat': echo $this->__('Saturday');
              break;
    case 'sun': echo $this->__('Sunday');
  }
  if(${$day.'_open'} != '')
    echo ": ".${$day.'_open'}.$this->__(' to ').${$day.'_close'}."<br>\n";
  else
    echo ": ".$this->_('CLOSED')."<br>\n";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Could anyone tell me why I got that error?

If I use the code bellow, everything works without any errors:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set(Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/timezone'));
$result=$this->getIsClosed(date('Y-m-d'));
if($result[0]){
  $today_open = $result[1];
  $today_close = $result[2];
} else {
  $today_open = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.strtolower(date('D')).'_open');
  $today_close = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.strtolower(date('D')).'_close');
}
$result=$this->getIsClosed(date('Y-m-d',time()+60*60*24));
if($result[0]){
  $tomorrow_open = $result[1];
  $tomorrow_close = $result[2];
} else {
  $tomorrow_open = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.strtolower(date('D',time()+60*60*24)).'_open');
  $tomorrow_close = Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/'.strtolower(date('D',time()+60*60*24)).'_close');
}
?>

<div class="box base-mini">
<div class="head">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('Business Hours')?></h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <?php if($today_open!='') echo $this->__('Today').": ".$today_open.$this->__(' to ').$today_close;
              else echo $this->__('Today: CLOSED') ?><br>
    <?php if($tomorrow_open!='') echo $this->__('Tomorrow').": ".$tomorrow_open.$this->__(' to ').$tomorrow_close;
              else echo $this->__('Tomorrow: CLOSED') ?>
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/fullscheduleurl') != '') ?>
<br><div align=center><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getStoreConfig('businesshours/general/fullscheduleurl'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View full schedule') ?></a></div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
echo ": ".$this->_('CLOSED')."<br>\n";
```

Should be:

```
echo ": ".$this->__('CLOSED')."<br>\n";
```

There is an underscore missing for translation method.

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the "Override CLOSE on these dates" to work. Do you know if Magento always keep the date in format M-D-Y? Or why this wont work?